# Can isotonic regression be used as a discretisation scheme?

Tags: isotonic, binning

Working on two different projects, one involving isotonic regression, the other being about discretising continuous variables. I was wondering if there is a link between isotonic regression and discretisation problems.

Isotonic regression is generally formulated as a quadratic programing problem :

$$ 
\min \sum_{i=1}^n w_i (x_i - a_i)^2 \text{ subject to } x_i \le x_j \text{ for all } (i,j) \in E.
$$

This can be applied when we don't have $ x_i \le x_j$. And we end up with something like that :

[image]

The step function we get can be used as a discretisation scheme.

Has this link between isotonic regression and discretisation scheme been studied ? Have the statistical properties of this discretisation scheme been studied ?